# List only all subdir´s with png´s inside in python with os.walk

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, directory-structure, os.walk, ipywidgets

i need some tips and help with my problem.
I want so make a dropdown menu in jupyter notebooks over a directory. Inside this directory are dir´s with png´s, and some dir´s with subdir´s with png´s. Now i wanna get a list of all dir´s with png´s inside. But not the dir´s with dir´s inside. ATM i get every dir, but thats wrong cause i just can use dir´s with png´s inside. Thats my code atm:

```
dir_path = 'Learning set/Calanus hyp/Chyp 1/'
path = 'Learning set/'   

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        if ([os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path)]) == True:
            namelist += [os.path.join(root,name)]

def get_and_plot(b):
    clear_output()
    global dir_path
    dir_path_new=test.value+"/"
    dir_path=dir_path_new
    global counter
    counter=0
    execute()

test.observe(get_and_plot, names='value')
```

As an example:
I have the directory "Learing Set" and wanna get a dropdown. But the dropdown menu shows me the dir´s Bubble, Bubble1, Bubble2 etc. The dir´s BubbleX have pngs inside. Thats correct. But the Bubble dir just implements the other BubbleX dir´s. What can i do, to get a list of all last subdir´s?

Comment: Question is very similar to [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3964681/2823755) - the difference being you want to *capture* the directories instead of the files themselves.  So not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`root` will be the current directory during the *walk*. If any of its files meet your criteria, add `root` to a list (or some other container).

```
dirs_i_want = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if any(fyle.endswith('png') for fyle in files:
        dirs_i_want.append(root)
```

If you want directories that **only** contain files that meet your criteria, use `all` in the conditional statement.

```
...
    if all(fyle.endswith('png') for fyle in files:
        ...
```